# javascript form does not lend itself to database designed

Tags: javascript, python

Javascript creates my html template tables. The function code below is called inside a for loop for TABLE which is inside a for loop for ROUND. The two loops are determined by variables (NumberOf)`tables` and (NumberOf)`rounds`, so they vary with use. The database needs to maintain records of the 6  fields for each TABLE in each ROUND, but those field names have not been programmed (yet?) to vary from one ROUND/TABLE instance to another for multiple reasons: it's not clear how to do so in a way to jeehaw with the python data models; I hope there is an easier alternative and; I want to not overburden the server with jinja-type code in the javascript as has been mentioned elsewhere on stackoverflow,  for example.

```
function round1(ROUND,TABLE){
        var tt;
        tt  =   '   <div class="table">Table '+ TABLE +''
        tt +=   '       <div class="flex-container partners1">'
            tt +=   '       partners1'
            tt +=   '       <input type="text"  maxlength="8" name="partner1" value="name' + Number(1+4*(TABLE-1)) + '"></input>'
            tt +=   '       <input type="text"  maxlength="8" name="partner2" value="name' + Number(2+4*(TABLE-1)) + '"></input>'
            tt +=   '       <input type="number" name="score1" >score1</input>  '
            tt +=   '       </div>'
        tt +=   '       <p>'
        tt +=   ''
        tt +=   '       </p>'
        tt +=   '       <div class="flex-container partners2">'
            tt +=   '       partners2'
            tt +=   '       <input type="text" maxlength="8" name="partner3" value="name' + Number(3+4*(TABLE-1)) + '"></input>'
            tt +=   '       <input type="text" maxlength="8" name="partner4" value="name' + Number(4+4*(TABLE-1)) + '"></input>'
            tt +=   '       <input type="number" name="score2" >score2</input>  '
            tt +=   '       </div>'
        tt +=   '   </div>'
        return tt;
    }
```

The data models are given below. I am concerned with the processing burden of Posting data back to the server and Getting the results back to the template. But I am also troubled with how to parse and process the data items efficiently.

```
class Parties(ndb.Model):
    email = ndb.StringProperty()
    page = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Pages)
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    tables = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    rounds = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)

class Rounds(ndb.Model):
    party = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Pages)
    number = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)

class Tables(ndb.Model):
    party = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Pages)
    number = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    partner1 = ndb.StringProperty(default="")
    partner2 = ndb.StringProperty(default="")
    partner3 = ndb.StringProperty(default="")
    partner4 = ndb.StringProperty(default="")
    score1 = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    score2 = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
```

So I am looking for ideas on how I can rewrite the javascript, or redesign the database, and how to construct the python get and post template_values to coordinate the two.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further analysis, I will attempt to rewrite my Python code to do much of the processing that is done now with javascript, hoping that the mismatch of data and code can be minimized. I was hoping to get ideas of ways to avoid such a rewrite by asking this question.

Or to minimize Python recoding because there is much javascript code not shown that would also have to be redone, I may revise the javascript code so that each input name includes its round and table values: for example, instead of `name="parent1"`, `name="r0t0parent1"` for parent1 in round 1 and table 1. Python code should be able to parse self.request.get's of such names and hopefully the jinja2 template responses will not be too burdensome to create and parse, but I do not look forward to developing the additional jinja2.  Perhaps the ideas [suggested here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) can be employed. I welcome any further advice.